# Is synchronization needed inside FinalConstruct()/FinalRelease()?

Tags: visual-c++, com, concurrency, synchronization, atl

In my free-threaded in-proc COM object using ATL I want to add a member variable that will be set only in [`FinalConstruct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afkt56xx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and read only in `FinalRelease()`. No other code will ever manipulate that member variable.

I doubt whether I need synchronization when accessing that member variable. I carefully read ATL sources and looks like those methods are always called no more than once and therefore from one thread only.

Is that correct assumption? Can I omit synchronization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the assumption is correct. Think of it as an extension of the C++ constructor and destructor. In theory, you could call a method on a COM object from a different thread, while `FinalRelease()` is executing. Although, that is undefined behaviour, and not an expected occurrence. You shouldn't try to protect yourself from it, just as you wouldn't try to protect yourself from other threads in a destructor. If you have to protect yourself in the destructor, the design is generally broken (it would indicate that you do not have a proper termination protocol between your threads).

The only way `FinalRelease()` could be called from another thread, is when the client code does not have a valid reference count to your object, or if some other parts of your code is releasing twice. This is a hard error, and will probably end up in a crash anyway, totally unrelated to any synchronization errors you might have. The ATL code for managing object reference count is thread safe, and will not leave any race conditions open.

As for `FinalConstruct()`, a reference to the object is not returned to any client before `FinalConstruct()` has finished with a successful return code.